# Issue with running with puppeteer with Symfony Webpack encore

Tags: symfony, webpack, puppeteer

I have installed [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) in Symfony using webpack encore.
When I tried to build I got the following error.

> warn  in ./node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/loaders.js                                                                             10:53:50 PM
>
> Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> warn  in ./node_modules/yargs/build/index.cjs                                                                                   10:53:50 PM
>
> Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
>
> ERROR  Failed to compile with 125 errors                                                                                        10:53:50 PM
> Module build failed: Module not found:
> "./node_modules/@tootallnate/quickjs-emscripten/dist/generated/emscripten-module.WASM_RELEASE_SYNC.js" contains a reference to the file "fs"

I don't know why this error is coming. As far as I know, this is not from Puppeteer.

In app.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
```

Webpack

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
    .addEntry('screenshot', './assets/screenshot.js')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = '3.23';
    })
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

this the log file

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
> 1 verbose cli [
> 1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
> 1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
> 1 verbose cli   'run',
> 1 verbose cli   'dev'
> 1 verbose cli ]
> 2 info using npm@6.14.13
> 3 info using node@v14.17.0
> 4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
> 5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
> 6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
> 7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
> 8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\wamp64\www\mws\node_modules.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Symfony;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn;C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.2.0;;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Users\Pranam\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Pranam\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Pranam\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Pranam\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets
> 9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: C:\wamp64\www\mws
> 10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'encore dev' ]
> 11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
> 12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
> 13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `encore dev`
> 13 verbose stack Exit status 1
> 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
> 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:376:20)
> 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
> 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
> 13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
> 13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
> 14 verbose pkgid @
> 15 verbose cwd C:\wamp64\www\mws
> 16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
> 17 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
> 18 verbose node v14.17.0
> 19 verbose npm  v6.14.13
> 20 error code ELIFECYCLE
> 21 error errno 1
> 22 error @ dev: `encore dev`
> 22 error Exit status 1
> 23 error Failed at the @ dev script.
> 23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Has anyone resolved this?

Comment: Have you tried with `import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';` instead of your require instruction which seems to create this error ?

Comment: @Simon did but same error.